# variables within controller foreach returns NULL inside view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a web application built using codeigniter. What I'm trying to do is show a summary of results on my view. In my controller I have the below code

```
function index() {
    $data['summery'] = $this->Main_model->get_summery();

     foreach ($data['summery'] as $d) {

        $data['total_week']  = $this->Main_model->get_total_week($d['i_id']);

        $data['total_month'] = $this->Main_model->get_total_month($d['i_id']);

    }
}
```

The problem that im having is each summery record has total weekly count and a monthly count based on the `i_id`

in my view i loop through the summery and it display the summery but when i `echo $total_week` or `echo $total_month` its always returns `NULL`

```
$data['total_week']  = $this->Main_model->get_total_week($d['i_id']);
$data['total_month'] = $this->Main_model->get_total_month($d['i_id']);
```

When i do a var_dump on the above variables it shows the number, but when i try to echo it on the view it returns NULL

Comment: I think you need to pass `$data` into your views as `$this->load->view(YOURVIEW', $data);`

Comment: need to `echo $data['total_week'];` instead of `echo $total_week`

Comment: @Saty Thats how im passing the data to the view

Comment: @AlivetoDie in the view i need to use `echo $total_week` or else it will give an undefined variable error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I under stood correct Try something like this

```
function index() {
    $this->load->model('main_model');

    $data['summery'] = array();

    $summery = $this->main_model->get_summery();

    foreach ($summery as $d) {

        $data['summery'][] = array(
            'total_week' => $this->main_model->get_total_week($d['i_id']),
            'total_month' => $this->main_model->get_total_month($d['i_id'])
        );

    }

    $this->load->view('the_view', $data);
}
```

View

```
<?php foreach ($summery as $something) {?>
    <?php echo $something['total_week'];?>
    <?php echo $something['total_month'];?>
<?php }?>
```